# Connection to a Oracle Database using session_start

Tags: php, database, oracle

I'm a IT-Apprentice in Switzerland currently working on a project for work. I'm very new to PHP so there may be some unclear points which I will address when they arise. I didn't find anything helpful on Google.

Onto the project.

I have to be able to connect to a Oracle SQL Database with PHP. On this "Webpage" I will have to Insert, Update and Delete Data from a existing Oracle SQL Database.
The way users will authenticate themselves is by just entering there Username and Password. The database host name and service name should be saved in the php file as it will always be the same. There are different users with different rights.
I'm wondering how I can get a session running until the user disconnects from it.
An example of how the user navigates through the webpage is as follows:
Login (Users login with there Oracle Database Accounts) -> Search (search through various tables in the database) -> Results (able to select a result) -> Edit (able to edit the found data and save it) -> Logout/Back(able to logout or go back to the search results).

I've accomplished a connection to the Database using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DB Connection</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', '//hostname:port/servicename');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 from table_name1 WHERE ROWNUM <= 20');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

How can I extract the connection info to a Login page and give over all the necessary data so that I can Log in and navigate through the website without a problem?

If there are any Questions (there probably will be) please ask them. I'll do my best to answer them with the knowledge I have.

Thank you very much

**Ben**

Comment: ok, so where does `session_start();` come into play; did you try anything? As it stands, this is a *"can you code this for me?"* or *"can you instruct me how to do this?"* type of question. There are ample tutorials out there to use sessions with, not to mention many Q&A's here on Stack. Have a look at the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php and http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php that should get you started.

Comment: I don't want somebody to code it for me. More of a help on how to do it.
I don't know how I should structure the code properly. As it stands I'm trying to figure out how I can get a Session started. I'm trying to get a starting point on how to send the connection info to another PHP file. I've looked at a lot of tutorials and I can't figure out how to cut the code so that it works.

Comment: Like I said, have a look at and start with the manual; it's all in there. You need to start the session inside all pages using sessions, assign a value to session array, then check if that session is set in subsequent pages, *and so on, and so on...*. - I believe I answered this in regards to the *latter* part of my comment up there ;-)

Comment: I'll have another look and try it.

Comment: I'm sure you *will* succeed. Just need to put your mind to it and keep trying until something gives ;-) Remember the operative word here, "will".